# Mixture Distribution, Create a Confidence Interval for unknown parameter

Tags: statistics, conditional-probability, parameter-estimation, confidence-interval

I imagine this question has already been asked, but I haven't found it yet.

Suppose there is a multiple choice question.  Some students know the answer, and others do not. If a student knows the answer they always get the question right. If a student does not know they guess randomly, there are four answer choices.

Suppose the probability of a student knowing the answer is $\pi$.  You only observe the selected answers.  How would you go about finding a $95\%$ confidence interval for $\pi$?

MY ATTEMPT

I let $X_i$ be an indicator variable that is observed.  $X_i=1$ if the student gets the correct answer, and $X_i=0$ if not.  I let $Z_i$ be an indicator variable for if a student knows the answer (0=does not know, 1=knows).

$$X_i=1 |Z_i = 0\sim Bern \left (\frac{1}{4}\right )$$
$$P(X_i=1 |Z_i = 1) = 1$$

Therefore,

$$P(X_i = x_i) = \left ( .25\right )^{x_i}\left ( .75\right )^{1-x_i}(1-\pi) + \pi$$

I am at a loss on how to make this into something more friendly or familiar to create a CI.  Although I can see a few ways to do this computationationally, that is not what I am going for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say the chance of answering a question correctly is $p$.  From the conditions of the problem,
$$p = \pi + (1 - \pi)\frac{1}{4} \tag{*}$$
From the observed answers, you can get a $95\%$ confidence interval on $p$ using the standard formula for a confidence interval on proportions.  This gives you limits on $p$, say $p_a < p < p_b$.  Now you can go back to (*) and solve for $\pi$ in terms of $p$ to find the corresponding limits on $\pi$.